# How to create clickable (on/off status) html elements binded to List<SelectItem>

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, onclick, viewmodel, dynamic-html

I need to create a massive of clickable html elements that have two states: puched/unpushed. Only one element in this massive can be in pushed state. It is similar to RadioButtonList. Also I have to bind the selected (pushed) element value to SelectedValueId in the ViewModel. Any help in this certain subject is appreciated! Thanks!
Here is the design of it: [image]

The only thing that I got till now is the heperlinks massive like this:

```
<div class="content-right">
                @foreach (var item in Model.AvailablePrivacyStatuses)
                { 
                    <a onclick="doTheJob(@item.Value)" href="#">@item.Text</a>
                }
            </div>
```

But how to get the value from doTheJob(@item.Value) into ViewModel?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. It's for fixing *existing* code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="content-right">
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedPrivacyStatusId)                    
@foreach (var item in Model.AvailablePrivacyStatuses)
                    {
                        <a data-id="@item.Value" class="selectable-button" id="status-link-@item.Value" href="#">@item.Text</a>
                    }
                </div>
                <script>
                    jQuery('div.content-right a')
                        .click(function () {
                            $(this).addClass('active');
                            $('div.content-right a').not(this).removeClass('active');
                            var id = this.getAttribute('data-id');
                            document.getElementById('SelectedPrivacyStatusId').value = id;
                        });


                </script>
```